# ng-model value inconsistency

Tags: angularjs, object, angular-ngmodel

Whenever we use `ng-model` on an input or select tag, getting `ng-model` object as `undefined` into the controller. 
But once touched an input getting proper object with property.

**Why :**

- On direct submit without touched the input getting `formData` as `undefined`.
- Once touched or enter the value in input box and on submit the form getting proper `formData` object.

  ```
  {
    "firstName": ""
  }
  ```

**Sample code :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.submitForm = function(formData) {
      console.log(formData);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form>
 <input type="text" ng-model="obj.firstName" name="firstName">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm(obj)"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: declare `$scope.obj = { "firstName": ""}` in controller then check.

Comment: I want to know the reason behind this different behaviour of same ng-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to initialize object if you don't want it to be undefined at page load.

Currently what is happening is when the input is "touched" the object to store the model is then initialized.

To initialize the object add this code:

```
    var obj = {
                "firstName": ""
              }
```

Comment: I want to know the reason behind this different behaviour of same ng-model.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer it is because before the input is touched the model does not exist because it has never being intialized. However when you use the input the model is automatically intialized in the background by Angular. So basically formdata is undefined because the object doesn't exist yet as it has not been initialized. Afraid I can't explain any better then that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Initialize `obj` object in the **controller**:

```
$scope.obj ={};
```

Comment: I want to know the reason behind this different behaviour of same ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with something like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.obj = {}

    $scope.submitForm = function(formData) {
      console.log(formData);
    };
});
```